# Intermittent network issues on Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon (wired)

Tags: networking

Often, when I initially try to click links to new websites or pull up a new browser tab and enter a URL I am confronted with an error message which states: DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG and I can usually click reload once or twice and fetch the intended resource.

However, this issue also seems to occur when I try and connect to any service via command line interface like Git push to a remote repository. Ruby's bundle command or Yarn's install command, particularly when installing a new package or gem and there is not an existing copy in the cache.

Eventually the command line tasks like git push and yarn i or bundle will resolve but they take a great deal of time.

I'm not inside a VM or anything weird. Just a straight wired connection.

I have tried to follow the instructions here [DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG error in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/622470/dns-probe-finished-bad-config-error-in-ubuntu-14-04) to no avail.

Comment: That seems like a Chrome and not a Ubuntu error.

Comment: How would that explain the fact that "git push" and other commands  also fail?